# Grails - Create tags and release version

Tags: svn, grails, tags, release, grails-plugin

I developed a Grails plugin and I need help with releasing. Now is the plugin version 1.0-SNAPSHOT and is saved in trunk folder on SCM server (`svn://svnserver/svnrepo/plugin/trunk`).

I need:

- create tag and save it in `svn://svnserver/svnrepo/plugin/tags/plugin_1.0`
- deploy artifact **plugin-1.0** into Nexus repository
- upgrade version in trunk to 1.1-SNAPSHOT and continue with development

Is in Grails a plugin, similar like maven-release-plugin for Maven? Or does anyone know a solution?

Thanks for your answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Grails Release Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/release) you can set it up to publish to either an internal nexus or get approved and setup to release the plugin to the [grails plugin portal](https://grails.org/plugins/).

Comment: Thank you! Have you a particular example of this setup?

Comment: When I use `grails publish-plugin` command, then plugin is upload to repository successful, but in subversion is no change. I get `Exception occurred trigger event [InitScm]: grails.plugin.svn.SvnScmProvider`
`WARN: No SCM provider installed.`

Comment: If you are using SVN you will also need to use the SVN plugin http://grails.org/plugin/svn

Comment: When I use this plugin and run `grails compile`, compilation fails with 24 errors: **unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core....**. I tried to look for documentation or instructions, but in vain. I don't know, how can I fix these errors and how do I configure this plugin.